# update another column based on another, group by, left join, AND, sum and where

Tags: php, mysql, cron

I have one query without " WHERE expiry date is less than today " i am trying to explain is as far as possible by giving example of code, db structure, and expected results below

```
$query="UPDATE users c
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT user_id, SUM(edexpf) as total
  FROM user_pages
  GROUP BY user_id
) x ON c.id = x.user_id 
SET c.edexpn = COALESCE(x.total,0);
";
```

Here is Example results i am getting with db structure

**users:**

```
    id       edexpn
========== ===========
    1         0
    2         4
```

**user_pages:**

```
          expiry     user_id    edexpf         type
         ========== =========== ==========  ==========
2015-11-15 07:17:34      2          1         Static
2016-12-15 17:00:01      2          1         Dynamic
2016-12-15 17:00:01      2          1         New
2016-12-15 17:00:01      2          1         Dynamic
```

> Now i am expecting results like this

**users:**

```
     id       edexpn
========== ===========
     2          2
```

> Because one of page from **user_pages:** where **user_id = 2** having 1
>   passed date page and 2 up coming expiry date pages and type not like static, 
> So, finally **i don't want to get sum of expired date pages and if type like static And Like New**

i think we can a add something like this

```
        // Where CURDATE() < DATE(expiry)
    AND type NOT LIKE '%Static%'
AND type NOT LIKE '%New%'
```

but not sure how

Comment: I suspect that a transaction comprising two queries will be as fast or faster than one, so I would be tempted to re-write this with an INNER JOIN

Comment: @Strawberry sounds good, but only using INNER JOIN not fulfill my goal, i have improved question please take a look if possible please rewrite it i tried with INNER JOIN But how to use conditions

Comment: Maybe this query can help you?

UPDATE users c
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT user_id, SUM(edexpf) as total
  FROM user_pages
  WHERE expiry > now()
  AND type not in ("Static","New")
  GROUP BY user_id
) x ON c.id = x.user_id 
SET c.edexpn = COALESCE(x.total,0);

Comment: @IvanM you wrote same answer as per my question, that not have condition at all :(

Comment: @IvanM let me test by your edited question now i am able to see some conditions in it

Comment: Which is why I mentioned two queries

Comment: @IvanM i have executed your query but not getting correct results

Comment: @IvanM well after removing this `AND type not in ("Static","New")` query is working we're so close to success cheers, so finally problem left in this area,  any suggestion on that, appreciate it

Comment: this depends on the data you have in the database, but the query i provided should be ok. Please provide more details so we can procced.